# How to remove element inside canvas from another event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, canvas

i am working in silverlight, i have a MouseMove event which draws something on canvas(child window)

```
 private void CanvasArt_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
      if (drawing)
     {
          Point current = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
          Line line = new Line() { X1 = start.X, Y1 = start.Y, X2 = current.X, Y2 = current.Y };
          line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
          line.StrokeThickness = 1;
          CanvasArt.Children.Add(line);
          start = current;
     }
 }
```

i have button on that child window

```
 private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

     this.DialogResult = true;
     ExtendedImage MyCanvasImage = CanvasArt.ToImage();
     CanvasArt.Children.Remove(line);// the 'line' is underlined in red marks and
     //says 'line' doesnot exist in current context
 }
```

how to solve this ?

Comment: If you only want to remove the line you can store a reference to it as a private field in your class. If you want to remove all elements you can use the function CanvasArt.Children.Clear()

Comment: Please post it as a answer. @FlatEric

Comment: done. posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove the line you can store a reference to it as a private field in your class. If you want to remove all elements you can use the function CanvasArt.Children.Clear()

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the Canvas's objects.

Canvas.Children.Clear()

this should clear the content on your Canvas

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to identify each element in the `Canvas`. If there are only a few of them, then you could just hold references to them in your code behind. However, if you could have many elements in the `Canvas` then you could use the `Tag` property to identify them:

```
 private void CanvasArt_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (drawing)
     {
          Point current = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
          Line line = new Line() { X1 = start.X, Y1 = start.Y, X2 = current.X, Y2 = current.Y };
          line.Tag = GetNextIdValue();
          line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
          line.StrokeThickness = 1;
          CanvasArt.Children.Add(line);
          start = current;
     }
 }

 private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {                
     this.DialogResult = true;
     ExtendedImage MyCanvasImage = CanvasArt.ToImage();

     // Retrieve line from CanvasArt.Children
     Line line = (from c in CanvasArt.Children
                  where c.Tag.ToString() == "SomeValue"
                  select c).FirstOrDefault() as Line;

     CanvasArt.Children.Remove(line);
 }
```

You can implement the `GetNextIdValue` method to return whatever ID values that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `line` is the local variable declared in `CanvasArt_MouseMove` you cant access local variable of another method.

You have two options

1. Find out your line from `CanvasArt.Children` collection
2. Store the line as a field in the class, not as the local variable.